# System property "javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory" for two different soap versions

Tags: java, web-services, soap-client, system-properties

i need to  communicate with two webservices from my application.
For one webservice i need to use soap1_1 version and for the other soap version is soap1_2. In this case what should be the value set for the system property "javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory"

Client 1:

```
public class SoapClient1 {


protected static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger ("TEST");
private static Long retryDelay = null;


public String sendSoapMessage (String xml) throws Exception {

    SOAPMessage resp  = null;
    String response = null;
    String endpoint = "http:xxxx";



    System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory","com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPMessageFactory1_2Impl");
    SOAPConnectionFactory connectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //URL endPoint = new URL(endpoint);

    //setting connection time out and read timeout

    URL endPoint = new URL (null, endpoint, new URLStreamHandler () {
        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection (URL url) throws IOException {

            URL clone = new URL (url.toString ());
            URLConnection connection = clone.openConnection ();
            connection.setConnectTimeout (60000);
            connection.setReadTimeout (60000);
            // Custom header

            return connection;
        }});


    try{

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();


            resp = soapConnection.call(getSoapRequest(xml), endPoint);      

        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        resp.writeTo(os);
        response = os.toString();


        if (!resp.getSOAPBody().hasFault()) {

            response = "SucCess:" + response;

            }else{

                response = "FaiLure:" + response;
            }

        }else{

            response = "FaiLure:" + response;
        }


    }catch(SOAPException se){
        _logger.log(Level.ERROR," Service Provisioning Call Failed");
        _logger.log(Level.ERROR,"The call duration before SOAPException =" +(end-start)+" ms.");

        se.printStackTrace();
        throw se;
    }

    soapConnection.close();
    return response;
}


private SOAPMessage getSoapRequest(String xml) throws SOAPException,Exception{

    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
    /* Create a SOAP message object. */
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = mf.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
    soapEnvelope.getHeader().detachNode();
    soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap","http://yyyy");
    SOAPHeader header = soapEnvelope.addHeader();



    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    InputStream stream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
    Document doc = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(stream);

    _logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "Adding SOAP Request Body");
    soapBody.addDocument(doc);

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    return soapMessage;

}
}
```

sample request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap="http://bridgewatersystems.com/xpc/tsc/entity/soap">
      <env:Header/>
        <env:Body>
             <TempTierChangeRequest xmlns="http://bridgewatersystems.com/xpc/tsc/entity/soap" credentials="root" principal="root">
           <temp-tier-change xmlns="">
                <service-components>
                     <service-component name="DSL_Tier_2"/>
                </service-components>
                <duration-sec>300</duration-sec>
                <description>1024 SC</description>
                <activation-date>2017-02-09T10:29:16</activation-date>
                <subscriber-id>26752018010@wholesale1.com</subscriber-id>
                <partition-key>26752018010</partition-key>
                <ttc-id>3706043</ttc-id>
                <validity-period>
                     <duration>30</duration>
                     <expires-with-billing-reset>1</expires-with-billing-reset>
                </validity-period>
           </temp-tier-change>
      </TempTierChangeRequest>
      </env:Body>
      </env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to set the value of System variable `javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory` for two different purposes. The default value is set for SOAP 1.1

Remove the system property `javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory` and depending on the type of client you are building use

**Building the soap message with `MessageFactory.newInstance()`**

If you want SOAP1.1, use the default constructor

```
 MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
```

If you want SOAP1.2, use

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
```

See [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnbhs/index.html).

**JAX-WS clients configured with annotations `@BindingType`**

`@BindingType` is used when the JAX-WS client is configured using annotations, for example if client is generated from WSDL. The annotation is added to Port to set the binding to `SoapBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING` or `SoapBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING`.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "https://myservice.services.com", name = "myserviceProxyProt")
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public interface MyServiceProxyPort {
```

Comment: I am building two clients to talk to two different webservices. have added the sample code of the two clients. For both the clients  i am using almost the same bit of code, just the endpoint differs. For both cases, i am building the body part of the request using xslt  and passing the generated   xml as input to the soapclient

Comment: I have updated the answer. See in the first case how to configure `MessageFactory.newInstance()` for Soap 1.1 or 1.2

Comment: i was doing the same earlier, but i was getting unsupported version error while parsing the response. the default value of javax.xml.xoap.messageFactory was set to SOAP1.1 and the response received was of soap1_2, so i added System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory","com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPMessageFactory1_2Impl"); to the code and it resolved the issue, i am yet to test the other interface which is of soap1.1 but i believe i will get the same unsupported error

Comment: Maybe is a namespace issue because you are writting directly the XML content.  See diferences between SOAP11 and SOAP12 here http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/Perl-SOAP-1-2-Request-Differences-SOAP-1-1-and-1-2.html. Please, set `soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");` for soap11 and `soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap","http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");` for soap12

Comment: do you mean, i should set the namespace explicitly even after setting the binding type?

Comment: Setting the binding type will add the namespace, but the soap body you add should reference to the correct namespace. And the are different in 1.1 and 1.2. Could you check if they match?

Comment: the soap body has the proper namespace and all the body elements belong to one namespace defined by the webservice

Comment: I have executed the code  configuring `MessageFactory.newInstance(protocol)`  with `SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL` or `SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL` and generates the SOAP message properly in each case. May be  you have a different issue. Could you post an example soap message for each protocol?

Comment: i found something on google related to this issue https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2010/11/19/soapsaajxml-issues-when-migrating-to-java-6-with-axis-1-2/

Comment: Are you using axis1.2 with java 1.6? I suppose you were using JDK's built in support for soap

Comment: yes i am using the built in soap support. Just curious what are the default values for the below system properties. i feel i messed up with these values. javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory
javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory
javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory

Comment: i have  set the   system property javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory to default value which is "com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl"  and tried to  generate the soap request of version 1.2. getting "java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message" error adding the request generated

Comment: I really think that on the client there is nothing special that has to be done. JAX-WS runtime can look into the WSDL to determine the binding being used and configures itself accordingly.

If you really want to change the binding on the fly you could try to use reflection

Comment: @Tom OP is not using jax-ws client and is not configuring the client using the WSDL bindings. He is bulding the SOAP message manually so it is needed a client configuration to specify different headers according the protocol supported by server

Comment: then he could use reflection to change the bindings on the fly

Comment: @Tom, really changing `MessageFactory.newInstance()` with soap_1_1 or soap1_2 parameter should do the work. But for some reason it is not working for OP

Comment: @Tom can you give sample code on how to use reflection for binding on the fly.